# Some Google Chrome Extensions Appearing Grayed Out and Popup will not Appear

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Two of my extensions Lastpass and Checker Plus for Gmail have grayed icons and upon clicking them the pop up box does not want to display. The extensions have no problems at work (running Ubuntu) and my laptop (Ubuntu) also has no issues, however my home desktop computer (Windows 8) has only recently had this issue. I'm not sure how to go about debugging this to find out what the core problem is here. I have taken the standard steps of restarting the browser.

[image: example]

Comment: Have you tried going to the "Extensions" menu (chrome://extensions/) and ticking the "Enabled" checkboxes for LastPass and Checker Plus?

Comment: @n.st There is no question I have them enabled, and if they were disabled they do not appear in the extension bar,.